# Dynamically adding and removing items to select jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

**Dynamically adding and removing items to select jquery**

Here is the example to add and removing items dynamically using jquery to select

**html**

```
<select id="List" class="form-control pull-left" style='width:40%'>
<option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="new">new</option>
    <option value="old">old</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="delete"
 value="delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
<br />

<input type='text' id="readme" class='form-control pull-left' style="width:40%" /><input id="add" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="add" /><br />

<div class="result"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#add').on('click',function(){
    $("#List").append('<option>'+$('#readme').val()+'</option>');
    $('.result').html('1 item added to select list').hide(2000);
});
$('#delete').on('click',function(){
    $("#List option:selected").remove();
    $('.result').html('1 item deleted to select list').hide(2000);
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxsnevzs/3/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @EWit, Now that's a good question...

Comment: Vote it if am right check demo or let me know best way to achieve this

Comment: WHAT IS THE QUESTION ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to work, except that notifications ("1 item added...") aren't seen after the *first* add or delete.  You can fix that by making sure to `show()` the results div first.

```
$('#add').on('click',function(){
  $('<option>').
    text( $('#readme').val() ).
    appendTo('#List');
  $('.result').html('1 item added to select list').show().hide(2000);
});

$('#delete').on('click',function(){
  $("#List option:selected").remove();
  $('.result').html('1 item deleted from select list').show().hide(2000);
});
```

Also, using `text()` instead of concatenating strings avoids problems if a user enters HTML into the input field.